# Import error in PyCharm even though importing from command line works

Tags: python, pycharm, pyramid

I am working on a pyramid project in PyCharm. I have all the packages installed and can import them from the command line. however, when i run my application run.py file

This is the line that is failing

```
    from pyramid.view import (
    view_config,
    )
```

it fails with

> no module named pyramid.view

I know pyramid is installed, and running `from pyramid.view import view_config` from the command line works, however it completely fails when trying to run the project.

I have tried both the original line and just having `from pyramid.view import view_config` but neither works.

I am using python 2.7.6 on ubuntu 14.04

[image: Screenshot of project interpreter config]

EDIT: I'm just going to blow away my Linux install and put windows back on.

Comment: Did you set up a virtualenv in your PyCharm project? Or install pyramid in a virtualenv from commandline?

Comment: or is the interpreter correctly configured in PyCharm?

Comment: There is a virtualenv, and it inherits global packages. Project interpreter is shown as the virtualenv 2.7.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure you have correct interpreter: go to **Pycharm Preferences** -> **Project: [your project name]** -> **Project Interpreter**. See list of packages installed and verify that you have pyramid within that list.

If you have pyramid installed try to re-open pycharm.

Install pyramid in your virtualenv:

```
source virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install pyramid
```

Comment: ran those commands. pip install shows pyramid is already installed.  pycharm project interpreter settings shows pyramid in the list of packages. I have also closed/reopened pyramid and rebooted the computer

Comment: try `pip uninstall pyramid && pip install pyramid`, the problem mainly with interpreter , try to select another interpreter in your execute configuration which you runs and then set proper interpreter.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall didn't work, nor did changing the interpreter.

Comment: please update your question with printscreen for `edit configurations` and projext interpreter view from preferences

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue and found the cause. Posting it here in case it is useful for anyone else.

Pycharm has the following couple of options in "Run/Debug configurations" (which are checked by default):

1. Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
2. Add source roots to PYTHONPATH

If any of the above two options are checked, your PYTHONPATH is essentially different from the command line. That can cause such issues.

For instance, in case you have a project with multiple folders in the project, where content of those folders are also installed as python packages (say using pip). Then the path to the module can be different in the two environments (commandline vs PyCharm).

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have your interpreter incorrectly set up in Pycharm or you have the wrong interpreter set up. Might want to check that out.

Comment: Project interpreter is set to the 2.7.6  virtual env, and it shows all the packages installed.  If i go to terminal and   execute workon develop, I can sucessfully do the import as well.

Answer (score 1):

Goto File>Invalidate Caches and restart pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten this to work. I believe my python install or Linux install is damaged, corrupted, or misconfigured. I am going to wipe the machine and reinstall windows.